# Change incoming packet source IP

Tags: centos, iptables, nat

How can I change the source IP of an incoming packet before it reaches the running service

I have two appliances, a Manager and a Server, connected via VPN and has NAT between them.

Manager Interface IP: A
Server Interface IP: B

Manager connects to Server using NAT IP Y and Server sees IP X when manager connects

How do I setup iptables on the Server such a way when packet arrives with source IP X, to alter it to IP.

I know this should be a non issue in a well designed network and product, but we need a workaround for the time being till it is fixed on software side.

So far the below iptables rules have been not helping:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <X> -o eth0 -j SNAT --to <A>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You saw [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243451/iptables-change-local-source-address-if-destination-address-matches) probably.

Comment: @e2-e4 yes that's where I got it from

Comment: I wrote in an earlier comment that it's not possible to SNAT (with conntrack and iptables) incoming packets. Actually this is not possible to do SNAT in *prerouting*. It 's actually possible to SNAT *input* packets (ie: packets already routed to the host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAT depends on services "asked" by *iptables* and provided by the *conntrack* subsystem. SNAT is not made available before the routing decision is made, but is still available once the packet was chosen to be routed to the host: in the rarely used *nat/INPUT* chain, as documented in the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#SNAT):

> `SNAT`
>
> This target is only valid in the nat table, in the `POSTROUTING` and
> **`INPUT`** chains, and user-defined chains which are only called from those
> chains. [...]

So as long as the Server is receiving the traffic (not routing it further), when receiving a packet from IP source address <X> on the server's IP destination address <B> through interface *eth0*, it can be SNATed to appear as source address <A> (which was the original IP source address, but this information is lost) instead, with this:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s <X> -d <B> -i eth0 -j SNAT --to <A>
```

Or using a simpler version:

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s <X> -j SNAT --to <A>
```

You could add more restrictions like `-p tcp --dport XXXX` (XXXX for the actual service reached), and you probably should: if you hit the problem described below, you might prevent yourself from accessing the system through the VPN. Have a backup access method or don't do it remotely unless sure.

The rule above might not be enough, because of routing. If the IP address <A> is not in a known route to the Server (this would happen only if the Server has no *default* route). While the system will never send a packet back (IP or even ARP) to this destination (replies are un-SNATed), a route to it is still needed for a correct handling by the routing stack which doesn't know SNAT happened.

So if the *iptables* rule above isn't enough (probably if the Server has no default route), you can add:

```
  ip route add <A>/32 dev eth0
```

Comment: The devices sit behind the router that is doing nat. the VPN doesn't terminate on the server itself.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't change much of the result. If you concur that the server handles iptables and receives traffic. Just replace tun0 or tun+ with just eth0 everywhere it's written. The route command still matters in your server is isolated and has no default route. I'll edit the answer later with those changes

Comment: Just changed (and simplified) the answer: it's the same method.